# Is it possible to use a converter within a style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, converters

Is it possible to use a converter within a style? For instance I am trying to create a styled `TextBlock` whose text resizes based on the `ActualHeight` property of the `TextBlock`. The resizing would be done via a converter.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. For example:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}">
                <Binding.Converter>
                    <MyConverter/>
                </Binding.Converter>
            </Binding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Depending on your exact scenario, you might also be able to use the more succinct:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get something similar to work by using:

```
<Setter Property="Text">
  <Setter.Value>
    <Binding Path="CompanyName">
      <Binding.Converter>
        <conv:UppercaseConverter/>
      </Binding.Converter>
    </Binding>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Hope it works for you too.

Yann

PS - CompanyName is the name of the actual ViewModel property I was binding the textblock to