# How do I databind the string property all in lower case in xaml?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-phone

I'm trying to do databinding on a Text property but I want it to show all in lower case

Can I do something in xaml to get HeaderTitle to display the Title property in lower case?

```
<TextBlock x:Name="HeaderTitle" Text="{Binding Title}" />
```

or I have to do HeaderTitle.Text = object.Title.ToLower()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a [Binding.Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) seems like the most direct approach.  If you go this route, you could [add the converter to a style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379032/99406).

Also, it looks like there is a [CharacterCasing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.charactercasing.aspx) property on the TextBox class as of the .NET Framework 4.5.  I realize you're asking about a TextBlock, but you may be able to style the TextBox in such a way that it works for what you need.