# Add space in DynamicResource?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to add a space before the text, my structure is like this:

```
<Setter Property="Text" Value="{DynamicResource oneMatch}"/>
```

so the content displayed should be: `" oneMatchContent"`

In the past I did a similar thing using `StringFormat`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding oneMatch, StringFormat=This is {0}}"/>
```

But I doesn't see any `StringFormat` on the `Value` for setter, any idea?

Comment: How about apply converter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378979/is-it-possible-to-use-a-converter-within-a-style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure, since you're so secretive about the context for all this, but my best guess is that that `Setter` is in a `Style` that you're applying to a `TextBlock`.

If that's the case, you could use a `Label` instead (or any other descendant of `ContentControl`), and set its `ContentStringFormat` property as well.

```
<Style 
    x:Key="oneMatchLabelStyle" 
    TargetType="Label" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}"
    >
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource oneMatch}" />
    <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="This is {0}" />
    <!-- Set padding to 0 so it'll look like TextBlock did in your layout -->
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
</Style>

...

<Label Style="{DynamicResource oneMatchLabelStyle}" />
```

If you want to add a leading space in the string resource itself, just specify a non-breaking space ([Unicode `U+00A0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings)) in the XAML. The HTML character entity `&nbsp;` isn't supported in XAML, so use a hex character entity instead:

```
<sys:String x:Key="oneMatch">&#xa0;Blah blah blah</sys:String>
```

And then use that resource without any special formatting.

Comment: for solve the problem instead in the `<system:String>` is possible add some space as in the html? Something &nbsp?

Answer (score 0):

You can get fancy with this approach :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="SecretKey">SecretText</sys:String>

    <Style x:Key="ContentKey" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Inlines>
                        <Run Text="&#xa0;"/>
                        <Run Text="{DynamicResource SecretKey}"/>
                    </TextBlock.Inlines>
                </TextBlock>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>            
</Window.Resources>
...
<Label Style="{StaticResource ContentKey}"/>
```

You can use any text in `Run` now.