# How to change App.xaml ressources dynamically at runtime

Tags: xaml, uwp

My application has some areas which get colorized by the color codes I get from a web application. I thought a lot about how to achieve this and I don't know how to approach this problem.

My first thought was to write a `ValueConverter` which just provides those colors so that I can debug whenever it did work.

But now that I'm trying to use it on some *styles* I ran into the problem that I can't use `ValueConverter`  in `App.xaml`.

So what I'm trying to archive is that when I navigate to something like the mainpage.xaml where no user specific content is shown I want to use the my company's colors but when the user navigates to pages where the content is user specific I want to display the company colors of the current user.

So I searched on *stackoverflow* how to accomplish this and I come across this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378979/is-it-possible-to-use-a-converter-within-a-style). But I always get an *binding failed* message in the output window.

```
<Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Binding Path="Background" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" TargetNullValue="a" FallbackValue="a">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <provider:DarkBackgroundProvider/>
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Any ideas or maybe an other approach on this?

I also **read** on some sites that I can **replace** values from `App.xaml`, but it did not work for me cause I got exceptions whenever I wanted to set the value of the `App.Resources[] = Color`

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed your binding data error and see it below:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in PresentationCore.dll
System.Windows.Data Error: 12 : TargetNullValue 'a' (type 'String') cannot be converted for use in 'Background' (type 'Brush'). BindingExpression:Path=Background; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Background' (type 'Brush') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Token is not valid.
```

The binding data error is not the issue of `DarkBackgroundProvider` but the issue of the `TargetNullValue` and `FallbackValue`.

You should create valid value for the two properties as below:

```
<Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Binding Path="Background" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}">
            <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
            </Binding.TargetNullValue>
            <Binding.FallbackValue>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
            </Binding.FallbackValue>
            <Binding.Converter>
                <local:DarkBackgroundProvider />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

By changing your code into the one I've posted above the binding data error has disappeared.

---

### Update

It's better to resolve your original issue instead of just resolve your binding error. Your original issue is to change a button style background due to the color you get from your web application.

So I've written the new code below to achieve your goal and it contains no converters.

```
<Application x:Class="Walterlv.Styles.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Walterlv.Styles"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush.MainButton.Background" Color="White" />
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Brush.MainButton.Background}" />
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This is the code-behind of the App.xaml. If you can get the instance of the `App` class you can change the color due to your newly calculated value.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        await Task.Delay(2000);

        Resources["Brush.MainButton.Background"] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0x00, 0x7a, 0xcc));
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me it appears in white not in the color from the provider

Comment: @MelloPs Of cause it does not work for you because you can never bind a property to the property itself and it definitely fails, that's the real reason why you fail. But you've asked another question that you get a binding error and you want to resolve it. I'll update my answer to resolve your original issue.

Comment: @MelloPs It's recommended to edit your question to post your original needs that you want to set the background of `Button` style from your provider.

Comment: Okay i did not know that this would make a difference since I thought the value converter would get the value when style gets applied so I thought that I only need this I will try this

Comment: Can I change the value at runtime? Because the specific problem ist that every user has its own color customization and user can be from more than on webapplication so the color needs to be changed when the user logs in

Comment: @MelloPs Notice the last line of the `App` class, you can see that I've changed the color of all the buttons to my specified color and you can also change it due to your web configurations.

Comment: The methods on StartUp is not recognized but I thought I could write a methods which does exactly the same but when I called it for setting the resource values I get this error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException so what I did navigated to the main page and wanted to set Color to the default app colors than I wanted to navigate to the area where the user is logged in so the colors from the web application gets displayed so I called a method from app where I set the resource values but it did not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189201/discussion-between-walterlv-and-mellops).